# 特定の1行（HTML）に紐づいているJSを特定する方法はありますでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, html, css

特定の1行のHTMLソースに紐づいているJSを
一番効率よく割出す方法はありますでしょうか？

具体的には以下となるのですが、
https://www.sony.co.jp/united/userexperience/support/ja_jp/?uxscc=set

例えば上記サイトの Gナビ部：【CSR・環境・社会貢献】
のアコーディオン時のレイアウトが崩れています。

この原因を追及しているのですが、 
その1つとして

```
<div class="navtray-w navtray-w-05 navtray-w-sp">
```

↓ ドリルダウン

```
<div class="cont-box"> 
<dl>
<dd>
<div>
<ul class="nav_list nav_list_3col">
<li class="nav_item" style="height: 85px;">
```

このリスト内の `style="height: 85px;"`

がべた書きされているのですが、 
htmlソース上にはもちろんなく、 
どこかのJSで制御されています。

この1行に紐づいているJSを特定したいのが、
今回知りたいことです。

私事で大変恐縮ですが、
どなたか効率的に割り出す方法がありましたら
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 紐付いているとはその要素のイベントをハンドリングしてる、とかですか？

Comment: 当方jsの知識が乏しくジャストな回答ができず恐縮です。
具体的には以下となるのですが、

https://www.sony.co.jp/united/userexperience/support/ja_jp/?uxscc=set

例えば上記サイトの
Gナビ部：【CSR・環境・社会貢献】
のアコーディオン時のレイアウトが崩れています。

この原因を追及しているのですが、
その1つとして

<div class="navtray-w navtray-w-05 navtray-w-sp">

↓ ドリルダウン

<div class="cont-box">
<dl>
<dd>
<div>
<ul class="nav_list nav_list_3col">
<li class="nav_item" style="height: 85px;">

このリスト内の

style="height: 85px;"

がべた書きされているのですが、
htmlソース上にはもちろんなく、
どこかのJSで制御されています。


この1行に紐づいているJSを特定したいのが、
今回知りたいことです。

私事で大変恐縮ですが、
どなたか効率的に割り出す方法がありましたら
ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 質問の補足は質問を編集、追記してください。(ところで当該ページの崩れは手元では起こりませんでしたがブラウザ等環境は？

Comment: あ、崩れてましたw

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます＞＜

Comment: bootstrapのスタイルが共通スタイル（includeStyleCommon_v5.cssなど）と干渉しているから崩れています。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chromeブラウザの検証機能で確認できると思います。

1. 検証したいDOMに対し右クリックして「検証」をクリック
2. HTMLパースペクティブで対象のDOMを右クリックして、「Break on > attribute modification」を選択
3. ページを再読込（F5等）
4. するとブレークが起きる
5. あとはStepOverやStep intoなどでJavascriptを追いかける。

今回は「高さの変更」なのでDOMの属性の変更の検知＝「attribute modification」
ですが、
子階層の変更の場合は「subtree modification」になります。

あとはGoogleのこの辺を参考にするといいかもしれません
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code?hl=ja