# あるDOM要素に対してクリック等した時に実行されるjsを突き止める方法

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools

たとえば「要素Xをクリックしたら何かしらの問題が発生する」といったバグの解析時に「クリックされた時にどのjsファイルの何行目あたりが実行されるか」が知りたいのですが、いい方法は無いでしょうか?

現状では、やむなく要素Xのidやclass値でgrepをかけてしらみ潰しに調べています。

ポイントは、各種ライブラリ内部のjsというより、現在調査中のブロジェクトのjsファイル・行番号を突き止めたいという点です。

ブラウザはChrome, Safari, Firefoxです。

Comment: 重複の可能性のある質問 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35205/

Comment: コメント有難うございます。リンク先の内容は要素の変更を伴っている場合は有効な感じがします。ただ今回の質問内容は単なる純粋なイベントも含みますので、重複というのとは違うかなと。

Comment: clickイベントハンドラを設定する方法は統一されていますか？　例えばjQueryのclickメソッドとか、on("click", ...)とか・・・もしそうであれば、可能な手段がありますが。

Comment: 質問内容はjs一般ですが、この質問をするきっかけになったバグにはjQueryのカスタムイベントが使われていました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chromeの「Event Listener Breakpoints」機能を使用して、クリック等の操作を起点とした処理のトレースを取る事ができます。

1. Google Chromeの開発者ツールを開く(F12)
2. Sourceタブを開く
3. Event Listener Breakpoints ペインを開き、Mouse → click をチェックする。

この状態で要素をクリックすると、実行されるJavaScriptソースコード上で処理が停止するので、F10等で処理をステップ実行させて、問題箇所を特定することができるかと思います。

Pause Your Code With Breakpoints  |  Tools for Web Developers  |  Google Developers
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。早速この手順でやってみました。中間にあるライブラリのどこかにはブレークします。ステップオーバー・ストップアウトなど繰り返してみましたがプロジェクトのソースコードには残念ながらたどり着けませんでした。恐らくこの方法は、ライブラリの実装の知識やソースコードの読み解きが必要になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ちなみに、ブレイクしたコード上で右クリックメニューを開き、「Blackbox Script」を選択することで、そのコード上ではブレイクしないようにすることも出来ます。これは開発者ツールのSettings->Blackboxingからも設定でき、ファイル名やパスのパターンで定義することができるため、中間ライブラリを除外するような設定を行うと追いやすいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます! Blackbox Script設定し、うまくたどり着けました!

Answer (score 1):

こちらの記事に書かれているやり方はどうですか？
Chromeのデバッガで各要素のEventListenerを調べられます。

[要素に設定されているイベントを調べよう](http://yuzu441.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/12/12/120000)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。早速この手順でやってみました。AncestorsをOFFにして最低段から順に確認しましたが何も表示されませ。逆にONにすると40個ほど表示されます。いくつか選んで"Show Function Definition"にて飛んでみると、ライブラリの内部のどこかが表示されます。この後ステップ実行などしてみましたが、残念ながらうまくたどり着けませんでした。40個の中の一個が正解かもしれませんが、素直に元要素のidやclassでgrepしたほうが速いという結果になりそうです(慣れによって解決するかもしれませんが・・・)